# How to know the Index in a List

Tags: c#

I have a a table called Persons with two columns(CountTalked(int),Age(int)), using entity Framework core 2.2 i get a list from this table something like this:

```
[
P1 = {CountTalked= 4,age= 25},//Index 0
p2 = {CountTalked= 3,age = 30},//Index 1
p3 = {CountTalked = 2,age= 33},// Index 2
p4 = {CountTalked = 1, age = 27 },// Index 3
p5 = {CountTalked = 0, age = 28} // Index 4
]
```

I have a class like this : classTest: {CountTalked = 2 }, if i compare my class with the list I want my class is in the position 3 if I compare it with the list

[image]

,y question is how can i get the position in order to a CountTalked of the ClassTest sent.
If my classTest has a CountTalked = 5, then my position will be => 1

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here? `pTest` doesn't match any of the list entries, are you saying you want to know where it would appear in the list, if it's ordered by `money`?

Comment: Yes, i Wanna to Know where it would apear(in what index) if it would be in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to know where that person would fit on the list, you don't have to sort the list for that, all you need to know is how many persons have less money (or the same amount of money) - a Simple count would give you the answer:

```
var index = Persons.Count(p => p.Money <= pTest.Money);
```

The fact that indexes are zero based means that this count will give you the next index on the list where pTest would fit.

This is more effective then ordering the list and then selecting items from it, since you only iterate the entire list once.

Comment: Yes, but when there are various persons with the same amount of money it should returns the same index for this persons,but when i substract th count of persons with the same amount of money the index(position) change...

Comment: @AndresGuillenHernandez I'm not really sure I understand your comment. Perhaps change `<=` to `<` and see if that helps.

Comment: I edited my question, i think it should be more clear for you, please check it again, thanks advanced !!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to correctly handle the case when `pTest` would not appear in the list (when `pTest` has less money than the last person in the list) then you need to handle `null` values.  Below code uses null-propagation operator `?.` along with the null-coalescing operator `??` to return a value.

```
var targetIndex = persons.OrderByDescending(p => p.money)
                         .Select((person, index) => new { Person = person, Index = index })
                         .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Person.money < pTest.money)?.Index 
                  ?? persons.Count;
```

**Explanation**

- `.Select((person, index) => new { Person = person, Index = index })` this creates a *projection* from `Person` to an anonymous type which contains `person` and the index of `person` and returns an `IEnumerable`.
- `.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Person.money < pTest.money)` we select the first person that has less money than `pTest`, this is where `pTest` would appear in the list.
- `)?.Index` selects the index. `FirstOrDefault` will return null if `pTest` has less money than all other persons in the list, `?.` returns null in this case
- `?? persons.Count` is used only if the above point applies (ie, `pTest` comes last).  In that case `pTest` would be in the last position of the array with index `persons.Count`

If you're ordering by ascending rather than descending the same logic would apply, just change the comparison in `FirstOrDefault` to `p => p.Person.money > pTest.money`.

Comment: In a sense it is a list of anonymous type and that is correct. But a better way of explaining it, is that a `Select` is used to create a *projection* (it projects from one type to another) which contains the anonymous types....See [Projection Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations)

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I don't know why, but I always forget the correct terminology for `Select`! Thanks for the link, it's about time I read through the whole `LINQ` section!

Comment: One forgets because its an `interview` question which seems to be the only place it is discussed as such. :-)